# Dav to MP4 using ffmpeg doesn't create the intended file

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg

I had the code from github and it didn't work as mentioned

```
#!/usr/bin/python

print ("Converting all of the .dav files in this current directory into .mp4 files using 
ffmpeg")
import os
from subprocess import call
import ffmpeg as ffmpeg

files = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(f)]
for f in files:
ext = f.split(".")[-1]
if ext == "dav" or ext == "DAV":
    mp4Name = f.replace("dav", "mp4")
    print ("Converting: " + f)
    ffmpeg ,'-y', '-i', f, "-vcodec", "libx264", "-crf", "24", mp4Name
    
    print ("Converted: " + f)
```

but it doesn't create the intended mp4 file.
what am I doing wrong?

Comment: No errors? Is the phyon code the problem, or is ffmpeg the problem? Does ffmpeg execute? If it does, then show the complete log from the ffmpeg process. Does ffmpeg work if you run it in a command-line interface?

Comment: When i try to run this command on CMD it says ffmpeg isn't a command

Comment: It worked after i downloaded ffmpeg from their site (https://www.gyan.dev/ffmpeg/builds/)and it worked fine in cmd thanks alot